# How to add all classes in a namespace as singletons in one line using IServiceCollection and dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Using default .Net dependency injection framework with `IServiceCollection`, is there a way to register automatically classes found in a given namespace?

I would like to add them as singletons in one line instead of adding them individually like this:

```
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterServicesCoreData(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services
            .AddSingleton<FileLoader>()
            .AddSingleton<FileLoaderGenericAggregateServices>()
            .AddSingleton<FileLoaderCoreAggregateServices>()
            .AddSingleton<CsvReaderGeneric>()
            ;
    }
```

Comment: To what end? Your extension method does that for where ever it is going to be called. ie `services.RegisterServicesCoreData()`. To get what you want you would need to use reflection and manually add the classes that belong to the desired namespace.

Comment: Hi @Nkosi thanks for your reply. Mostly for maintenance reason, right now every time I add a new service I have to add a registration manually. With namespace auto-registering it would help!

Comment: Then reflection would be the path to take for that convention over configuration approach. Load the assembly and select all types that belong to the desired namespace and add them to the service collection.

Comment: Other than namespace, do they share anything else in common, or is that all.